# How is $f(x)$ formally defined?

Tags: functions

I understand that a function is a relation with certain restrictions; a set, at the end, but how is $f(x)$ defined, the action of applying in a way $f$ to $x$? Can it only be defined using "if and only if" condition? like in

$$f(x)=y\iff (x,y)\in f$$

Isn't there an algebraic form for function application that define them without using logical statements? I feel like if you need to define a function, you need to involve a certain logical operator.

Comment: What does $(x,y) \in f$ mean in your expression?

Comment: I'm not sure if you are asking about how to define a function or how to define the concept of function.

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> " algebraic form for function application "

I don't know what that means.  And surely trig functions can't be defined "algebraically".

> without using logical statements?

What's wrong with "logical statements"?  We certainly can't define anything with *illogical* statements.

And *all* definitions are like this. "A triangle is isosceles $\iff$ the triangle has two equal sides"

Okay...

Intuitively we have an *idea* and *concept* of "function" in that if we have two sets $X$ and $Y$ we can imagine a mapping in which every element $x$ of $X$ will get assigned to an element $y$ of $Y$.  And the "function" is the mapping as a whole.

Okay, that's seems utterly clear to me but not at all rigorous.  How do we formally define "mapping" and have the idea of mapping expressed  as an *object*?

Since a mapping $X$ to $Y$ is actually a collection of individual maps of $x_\alpha$ to $y_\alpha$ then a *function* will be expressible as set $\{x_\alpha \mapsto y_\alpha\}$ where the notation $x_\alpha \mapsto y_\alpha$ means a specific assigning $x_\alpha\mapsto y_\alpha$.

But what is a "assigning".  Well, that's nothing more or less than saying "here we take this $x_\alpha$ and tie it to this $y_\alpha$" which nothing more or less than making an ordered pair $(x_\alpha,y_\alpha)$ where we say the first term is paired to the second pair.

So we define a function $f:X\to Y$ (or $f$ for short) as a subset of $X\times Y$ where $X\times Y = \{(x,y)$ ordered pairs where $x \in X$ and $y \in Y\}$.  However as we are assigning *every* specific element of $X$ to *one* specific element of $Y$ the set $f \subset X\times Y$ must have the condition that for every $x \in X$ there is exactly one and only one $(x,y) \in f$.

So that is the definition of a function.  The vague concept of a "mapping" is now a concrete "object"; a set of ordered pairs.

Now your question about $f(x) =  y \iff (x,y)  \in f$ is just one of notation.  We define the notation of $f(x) = y$ to mean $x \mapsto y$ is some "mapping" so that $(x,y) \in f \subset X\times Y$ for a specific subset $f$ which ... follows the rule that for *every* $x \in Y $ there is exactly one $(x,y) \in f$.

And the $\iff$ should not be thought of as being some thing that only exists in boolean logic world but instead is simply a matter of how we *declare* definitions.  For example "$X$ is a pelican $\iff$ $X$ is an aquatic bird that ... is whatever it is that makes a pelican a pelican" is the definition of *pelican*.

... Oh... maybe you are wondering how we can do something like taking a "rule" such as $f(x) = x^3 + 7x^2 + 3$ and have it somehow be a set of ordered pairs.

Well, $f(x) = x^3 + 7x^2 + 3$ is simply shorthand notation  for $f = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R\times \mathbb R| y = x^3 + 7x^2 + 3\}$.

Of maybe I should say $f = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R\times \mathbb R| y = x^3 + 7x^2 + 3\}$ is simply the concrete objectification of the abstract mapping conceptual rule of $f(x) = x^3 + 7x^2 +3$.

Answer (score 2):

One way is a function $f: X \to Y$ is a set

$$f  \in \{A \subseteq X \times Y: \forall x \in X, (x,y) \in A \land (x,z) \in A \implies y=z\}$$

So $f$ is a particular set of ordered pairs such that each element in the domain maps to one and only one element in the range.